# Probability that sum of 2 random numbers are less than an integer

Tags: probability, random-variables

Assume there is an Ideal Random Number Generator which generates any real number between 0 and given integer. Two numbers are generated from the above generator using integer A and B, let's assume the numbers generated are X1 and X2. There is another integer C. What is the probability that summation of X1 and X2 is less than C.

Comment: The density has the shape of a roof, starting at 0, with positive slope s on some interval (0,c), with null slope on (c,d), and with negative slope -s on (d,d+c), for some suitable s, c and d. Now, what did you try?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Draw the sample space on axes $X_1, X_2$.  You should get a rectangle of area $AB$.  Now shade the portion $X_1 + X_2 < C$ in this rectangle.

Now consider cases where $C \in \,$ one of the following intervals  $(0 < \min(A, B)), [\min(A, B), \max(A, B)], (\max(A, B), A+B), (A+B, \infty)$...

Comment: can you elaborate your answer further?

Comment: @Kaushal28 Have you tried drawing for any particular case? Where do you need more elaboration?

Comment: But I can't understand how to draw sample space on axes X1, X2.

Comment: @Kaushal28 Missed your Q.  Check http://sketchtoy.com/67283206  The rectangle is your sample space, the shaded region is the event you're interested in.  Their ratio is the probability you seek.  Depending on $C$, the shaded region changes...